# What Layer2Bridging mean and do I need to be enabled?

Tags: router

I have in my router this setting Layer2Bridging and I dont understand the description

> Specifies bridges between layer 2 LAN and/or WAN interfaces.
>
> By default, unbound ports will be bound to br0 when the gateway is
> restarted.

Do I need this enabled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bridging connects the ports together into a single subnet, bypassing the actual "router" part of the router – it's how the LAN ports as well as Wi-Fi are usually connected together (while the "router" sits between LAN and WAN).

For a "main" router, you want bridging between all LAN interfaces, but *not* the WAN port – generally it's set up by default and you shouldn't need to enable anything manually.

For a "secondary" router that's only used for additional Wi-Fi/Ethernet (if you don't actually need a separate IP subnet, etc), adding the "WAN" port to the main LAN bridge would turn it into an additional LAN port if needed.

Comment: I have WAN Interface list has some options enabled like `INTERNET_TR069` should I disable them for security or leave as it is ?